# openmpi + java, could not find or load main class

Tags: java, mpi, noclassdeffounderror, openmpi

I am recently trying out the java binding of the openmpi library :

I have succesfully compiled the lib with the following configurations:

```
$/configure --prefix "/home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi" --enable-mpi-java --with-jdk-dir="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/" --with-jdk-header="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/include/"

$sudo make install
```

I am able to compile a simple java program with : `$mpijavac src/com/cyc115/pa2/Main.java`

currently `$echo $CLASSPATH` gives `/home/yuechuan/Github/parallel_pa2/src/com/cyc115/pa2/`

However I am having trouble to get the class file to run. Here are some alternatives I have tried so far:

```
$java -Djava.library.path=/home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi/lib/mpi.jar -cp .:/home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi/lib/mpi.jar Main
```

which returns `Error: Could not find or load main class Main` error.

the pure and simple `$java Main` command returns `NoClassDefFoundError`

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: mpi/MPIException
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Class.java:3048)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Class.java:3018)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1784)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(LauncherHelper.java:544)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:526)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: mpi.MPIException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

Here's the java file if anyone needs :

```
package com.cyc115.pa2;

import mpi.MPI;
import mpi.MPIException;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws MPIException
    {
        MPI.Init(args);

        int rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getRank();
        int size = MPI.COMM_WORLD.getSize();

        System.out.print("hello world");
        MPI.Finalize();
    }
}
```

Any ideas on how I can get the .class to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the package is :

```
package com.cyc115.pa2;
```

You need to put the file Main.java in a sub-directory named `com/cyc115/pa2`
The java library path should be a path to the directory containing `libmpi_java.so` rather than the path to mpi.jar.

To compile:

```
javac -cp /home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi/lib/mpi.jar com/cyc115/pa2/Main.java
```

To run:

```
java -Djava.library.path=/home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi/lib/ -cp .:/home/yuechuan/Application/.openmpi/lib/mpi.jar com.cyc115.pa2.Main
```

The following is not the problem, just an FYI:

It should be `--with-jdk-headers` with an s rather than `--with-jdk-header` however you do not have to specify it at all if you are already specifying `--with-jdk-dir`.

Comment: And note this correctly has java.library.path as the directory, not the jar file as the question did.